# Should the tags 'ambiguity' and 'confusables' be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[confusables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusables) seems like a synonym of [ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity), should it be merged?

Comment: Absolutely definitely not. Confusables are things like *there/their,* ambiguity is lack of precision due to poor phrasing or insufficient detail.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That makes sense; could you put it into an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: I edited both tag wikis to make each tag more distinct. It's still in the review queue. But the 5k+ users can vote it into effect shortly. Looking through the questions in both tags we could use a quick review kicking the tags out from some of these questions.

Comment: My tag wiki edits have been approved. I think now these tags are reasonably distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my limited experience with these tags, they mean different things.

"Confusables" is about words (or other things) that speakers or learners commonly confuse. For example, "what is the difference between ['deprecated' and 'depreciated'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/why-is-there-confusion-between-depreciated-and-deprecated)?" People asking these questions want to learn about some distinction so they can avoid making the mistake of confusing these terms.

"Ambiguity" is about ambiguous structures. Ambiguity is not necessarily, or even usually, a mistake. People asking about ambiguity may want to know how to interpret an ambiguous sentence, or they may want to know about alternative ways of phrasing that are less ambiguous.

Comment: I agree and there are good questions supporting this in the respective tags. I edited the tag wikis accordingly.